# How can i make it so that a member has to ping another member in a ,user command using discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot which uses a prefix. I want to make a user info command. How can I make it so that the member using the command has to mention another member or it will return with a message saying you must mention a member and how can I get the member that was pinged info.

This is my command so far:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message, args) => {
 if (message.content === ',user') {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const userinfoEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('User Info')
        .setDescription(`Testing`)
        .setColor('#2e2f36')
        message.channel.send({embeds: [userinfoEmbed]});
    }
})
```

I used the ,user command and it did respond with the embed with Testing inside of it but when I tried doing ,user @user it didn't respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user use `,user @mention` the message content is `",user <@!id>"` not the `",user"` that's why the condition returns `false` and doesn't respond.

You should compare like this

```js
if (message.startsWith(`${prefix}user`)) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Please check this out for more information https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp